# reading in from socket until I get enough bytes

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to read in an integer which is going to let the server know the message length. I read until I reach `sizeof(int)` bytes using a while loop. I'm following the same convention for the message and length using a while loop to call recv multiple times. If all I'm doing is reading a int can I just call recv directly and expect all the bytes?

If not then how should I read in a integer using a while loop.

```
struct CONN_STAT {
    int size;      // length function should return the length into this field
    int nRecv;     // bytes sent of message
    int nSent;     // bytes received of message
    int lRecv;     // bytes received of length 
    int lSent;     // bytes received of length 
};
```

server : How I'm reading length

I copied the logic from my message function it reads similar to this
but info is replaced by a char array and the (info + pStat->lRecv) works for it

```
int readLength(int sockfd, int * info, struct CONN_STAT * pStat){

    int infoSize = sizeof(int);

    // I copied the logic from my message function it reads similar to this 
    // but info is replaces by a char array and the (info + pStat->lRecv) works for
    while(pStat->lRecv < infoSize){
        int n = recv(sockfd, info + pStat->lRecv, infoSize - pStat->lRecv, 0);

        if (n > 0) {
            pStat->lRecv += n;
        }
        else if (n == 0 || (n < 0 && errno == ECONNRESET)) {
            close(sockfd);
            return -1;
        }else if (n < 0 && (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) { 
            //The socket becomes non-readable. Exit now to prevent blocking. 
            //OS will notify us when we can read
            return 0; 
        }else {
            printf("Unexpected recv error.");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Calling it like this

```
readLength(sockfd, (int*)pStat->size, pStat);
```

error: warning: cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Comment: The error is correct. An `int*` is not an `int`. Why isn't that argument just `pStat->size` ?? What was your hope-to-gain for adding that cast ?

Comment: I was getting a error when I didnt, since recv needs a void* for the buffer argument.

Comment: `readLength(sockfd, (int*)pStat->size, pStat);` - that isn't a call to `recv`. Look at the function id. `CONN_STAT::size` is `int`. Hard casting to `int*` may hide the warning or error, but that doesn't fix *anything*.  Again, what is `readLength(sockfd, (int*)pStat->size, pStat)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's supposed to get the length and put in into the size field of the pStat argument.

Answer (score 4):

> If all I'm doing is reading a int can I just call recv directly and expect all the bytes?

Generally speaking, no.  TCP is a *byte-streaming* protocol, so it doesn't guarantee anything about how many bytes will be delivered by any one call to `recv()`.  It's entirely possible (and therefore, given enough time, inevitable) that you'll `recv()` only the first part of the integer from a given `recv()` call, and you'll need to save the bytes you've received into a buffer somewhere and plan to append the rest of the bytes to that buffer later on.  You can only actually parse/use the received integer after you've collected the whole set of bytes that were used to represent it.

> If not then how should I read in a integer using a while loop.

Pretty much the same way you are (presumably) reading in the data-payload that follows the integer:  write any received bytes into an array until the array has the number of bytes in it that are required to parse it.  (In this case, you need to have `sizeof(int)` bytes in your array before you can read the integer as an integer... and don't forget that `sizeof(int)` may be a different value on different machines, and that an `int` may be represented in either big-endian or little-endian form.  You might want to use `int32_t` instead of `int`, and `htonl()` and `ntohl()` to handle any necessary endian-conversion)

Since you're using non-blocking I/O, I suggest putting your collection-buffer into the `CONN_STAT` struct, so that a given call to `readLength()` can update the array with any received bytes and then a subsequent call can update the array some more, and so on.

The way I think about is to just see it as receiving two data-buffers:  The first buffer I can assume the size of -- it will always be `sizeof(int)` bytes long.  The second buffer I will know the size of as soon as I have received the entire first buffer and can read what it contains.  So I can use (almost) the same logic for both of the two buffers, and then repeat as necessary.

Comment: For the endianness do I have to convert it before I send and after I receive. For example, client converts length to network order and then sends and server receives and converts to host order?

Comment: @AbdiWali yes -- send the big-endian integer returned by `htonl(bufferLength)`, and on the receiving side, don't just use the received value verbatim; instead call `ntohl(receivedValue)` and use the value it returns.  If you do that, your integer-transmission code will work as expected even if the sending and receiving machine are running on CPUs that have different native-endian-ness.

Comment: Btw note that `htonl()` and `ntohl()` both return a `uint32_t` and take a `uint32_t` as their argument, which is good because it means you can guarantee that the values you send/receive will always be `sizeof(uint32_t)==4` bytes long regardless of what `sizeof(int)` might be on the machine your code is running on.